# Expo v39 AppAuth cannot get a correct accessToken from azure

Tags: javascript, azure, react-native, expo, appauth

I can get an accessToken but when I parse it, it doesn't have my custom scope and correct audience. Here is a parsed token - [parsed accessToken](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Fdjs.png)

Here is a config that I used -

```js
const baseRedirectUrl = Linking.makeUrl('/redirect');
const config = {
      issuer: 'https://sts.windows.net/[tenantId]',
      scopes: [ "api://[api-key]/api-access" ],
      clientId: ApiConfig.ssoConfig.clientId,
      additionalParameters: { prompt: 'select_account' },
      redirectUrl: baseRedirectUrl,
    };
const authState = await AppAuth.authAsync(config);
```